# How to make a tab?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-tabhost, android-style-tabhost

new in android, i have 4 button on clicking  button1, it gives a new form...
box.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
public class Box extends CustomWindow {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


      Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
   b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(Box.this, Group1.class);

         startActivity(intent);
      }
   });

   Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
   b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(Box.this, Group2.class);

         startActivity(intent);
      }
   });

       Button b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b3);
   b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(Box.this, Group3.class);

         startActivity(intent);
      }
   });


   Button b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b4);
   b4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = new Intent();
         intent.setClass(Box.this, Group4.class);

         startActivity(intent);
      }
   });

}
}
```

group1.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
public class Group1 extends CustomWindow {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.group1);
}
}
```

Problem: How to make tabhost on group1?

Comment: Please, be gentle on the caps-lock and the urgent notes

Answer (score 0):

Public class group1 extends tabactivity.
Check the hello tablayout tutorial in the documentation.